# How do I put document.referrer inside a href?

Tags: javascript, html

Well, it's a basic problem, but I don't know how do I put a link to the previous page via `document.refferrer` inside href of an `a` tag?

Comment: `document.referrer` is not always defined, `history.back(1)` might be a better solution ..?

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! works just like I want it to